# Java Linked List - Continuous Loop

Tags: java

I have the following code, when i run it though debugger, it keeps on looping until it reaches stack overflow: null

```
public class List{
private list<String> strlist;
private String str1 = "zxc";
private String str2 = "ugh";


public List(String x, String y){
{
  strlist.add(str1,str2)
}
```

Can anyone try to solve this for me? Thanks.

Comment: Is the `list` class something you wrote? If so, we cannot help you unless you provide us its code (more specifically, it's `add(int,int)` method code).

Comment: That's not your real code, `private list<String>` will not compile unless you have a `list` class. Please post the shortest snippet that both compiles and reproduces your issue.

Comment: @Mat *"The shortest snippet that both compiles and reproduces your issue."* AKA an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html).

Answer (score 3):

Since this code doesn't even compile, I'm assuming your code looks like

```
public class List {
  private List strlist;
  public List(int x, int y) {
    strlist = new List(x, y);
    // strlist.add(x,y);
  }
}
```

The solution is simple: Don't create another instance of the same class in the constructor. Instead, you should first implement the actual list functionality, for example by constructing elements of a class `LinkedListValue` that holds a value and references to the next object in the list.